# Which is the best PHP beautifier extension for Sublime Text?

Tags: php, sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I have been working in Sublime Text for the last three months. I've found the extensions **HTML Beautifier**, **JS** and **JSON** 
beautifier.

Now I want a [PHP](http://php.net/) beautifier extension.

So can someone please suggest which extension I should use as a [PHP](http://php.net/) beautifier? If the extension also checks for PHP errors, then that is good for me.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

**[Sublime CodeIntel](https://github.com/SublimeCodeIntel/SublimeCodeIntel)** work for me

you can install this package in sublime  by package manager .

Comment: And how do you format your document using this plugin ?

Comment: I don't see any beautifier option within this plug-in.

Answer (score 8):

It was asked some time ago, but anyway, there is a good package, for many languages, here:
https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/CodeFormatter

Comment: FYI, CodeFormatter now breaks with PHP7.2